# SignalR Intermittent Failure to call client method

Tags: client, signalr

I am currently using SignalR 2.0 and MVC 5.0 for my project. All the signalR update works fine except when I have updated the web.config file which causes the application pool to recycle. This is the starting point I notice SignalR behaving inconsistently. Sometimes I need to perform an action multiple times before the SignalR update can be propagated to the client. I have enabled the SignalR logging and I can't see anything displayed in the log whenever it failed to propagate to the client.

Do we need to do something in the hub, like reconnect or anything when the app pool got recycled?

At the moment, i didnt do anything in terms of coding and simply refresh the page. But it gives me that problems with SignalR. And the only way to fix that intermittent problem completely is to reboot the server.

Have anyone experienced this kind of behavior in SignalR?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Editing the web.config effectively does reboot the server (or at least the app pool). It seems funny to me that rebooting the server is how you are fixing your intermittent client method invocation failures. Do the clients only miss calls shortly after editing the web.config, or do the intermittent missed calls happen indefinitely until you manually reboot?

Comment: the intermittent missed calls happen indefinitely until manual reboot.